# Get value from a generic object property by reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I just want to get main identifier from all domain object from a generic property.
The code until now:

```
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> customProperties = genericObject.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);

foreach (PropertyInfo justAuditElementProperties in customProperties) {

    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> elementsToAudit = justAuditElementProperties.PropertyType.GetProperties().Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof (AuditeAttribute)));
    foreach (PropertyInfo element in elementsToAudit) {
        string name = justAuditElementProperties.PropertyType.FullName + "." + element.Name;
        string value = element.GetValue( ? , null).ToString();
        atributoNomeValor.Add(name, value);
    }
}
```

What's the correct replacement to *?*

--
So is important to say that every main identifier has `[Audite]` attribute

**edit**
The type of ? is the type of a Property of genericObject. example:
Department is genericObject.
Manager is a property. 
So in this case I want `element.GetValue( ? , null).ToString();` where this element is a declared in Manager class as:

```
 [Audite]
 public string name { get; set; }
```

**Solution**
This use the solution from @liho1eye, I just added a null reference verification, that generate some problems for me.

```
var propertyParent = justAuditElementProperties.GetValue(genericObject, null);
string value = propertyParent != null ? element.GetValue(propertyParent, null).ToString() : "";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that would be the instance of your object

```
string value = element.GetValue(justAuditElementProperties.GetValue(genericObject, null), null).ToString();
```

Comment: you just added a level of nesting. The problem as is solution is exactly the same

Comment: But you agree that the type of an property of genericObejct is not the same type. I've tried you solution and I receive the error of type not match

Comment: I already gave you complete answer. That should work unless your question is wrong or incomplete. As a side note looking at the signature of `PropertyInfo.GetValue()` should be enough for you to figure out what to put there... The instance of the object which value you are trying to get.

Comment: Man, I can't say how shine (and happy) I'm right now! I lost basically one day of my life trying to solve this and reading numerous blogs. But everything is about an sandbox incomplete! The property is rally null. Well, let's move forward.

Answer (score 0):

Should be your `genericObject`.

As far as I can compile-it-in-mind, you are iterating thru the properties of `genericObject` only. Identifying properties that have 'AuditeAttribute', and then getting it's value.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for complete details

Comment: No. I want to pick the property, and then the identifier of this property. So the type is not os generic object and yes the type o some property of then. A kind of annoying

Comment: @Custodio I mean your genericObject variable from first statement in your sample.

Comment: I understand. But I've tried this. But I got some error like the types not match. And yes, the typer are different. I'll edit the question to explain better.