# Get C# Property Values for multiple objects

Tags: c#

I have couple of domain objects something like:

```
public class Person()
{
public int age { get; set; }
public string city{ get; set; }  
}

public class Company()
    {
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public string address{ get; set; }  
    }
```

I have another class which calls the MyMethod as mentioned below.

```
public class CallTest()
{
 Person p= new Person{age=10,city="dd"};
 Company c= new Company{name="mynae",address="myaddress"};
 MyMethod(p);
 MyMethod(c);
}
```

mi.Name gives me the property name. But how do I get the property value?

```
public class MyMethod(object obj)
{
    Type t = obj.GetType();
    PropertyInfo prop = t.GetProperty("Items");
    foreach (MemberInfo mi in t.GetMembers())
            {
                    if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
                    {
                       var x = mi.Name;
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get value from a generic object property by reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998832/get-value-from-a-generic-object-property-by-reflection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast `MemberInfo` to `PropertyInfo` to get it's value :

```
.....
if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
{
    var x = mi.Name;
    var value = ((PropertyInfo) mi).GetValue(obj);
}
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of property obj.Items you can use the following code

```
public class MyMethod(object obj)
{
    Type t = obj.GetType();
    PropertyInfo prop = t.GetProperty("Items");
    var x = prop.GetValue(obj, null);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, because we have to get value of the each property. When i tried your approach it throws null exception.

Comment: Ok i miss understood the question, i thought you were trying to get the value of "Items".